# Initialize image in django admin add form from another model image

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a model,

```
class Abc(models.Model):
    .
    .
    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to = path,default = 'images/nophoto.jpg')
    .
    .
```

And in admin list view for this model, have an Add button column which will load add form of another model admin (Xyz) which also have an image field. What I want is to initialize image in Xyz add form with image in selected Abc instance.

I have tried

```
def add_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        .
        .
    g = request.GET.copy()
    g.update({
        'image': abc_instance.image,
     })
    request.GET = g
        .
        .
```

In Xyz admin, and it shows image in form but on saving image is not getting saved.

What can I do to accomplish this?

Comment: What does 'pre load' mean? ie, you want the form to be prefilled with the value for that image?

Comment: @ChidG  Yes. Image field of add form need to be initialized with the other object image.